# Can someone explain about "Methods" in jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap-3

Take a look at this:
http://www.bootstrapwizard.com/

There a "Methods" section, I didn't understand what does it, there no example about using method.

In that case I don't know how to use this method "markAllVisited"

Does it mean look like in this code?

```
$(".wizard").bootstrapWizard(options).markAllVisited;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery plugins, methods are called by calling the plugin function and giving the method name as the first argument:

```
$(".wizard").bootstrapWizard("markAllVisited");
```

For other examples of this, see jQuery UI and jQgrid.

Comment: why the methods aren't called as functions?

Comment: It keeps everything contained within a single function.

Comment: How do you make it work with 2 things like options and methods like 
$(".wizard").bootstrapWizard(options, "markAllVisited");

This currently code didn't work.

Comment: `.bootstrapWizard(options).bootstrapWizard("markAllVisited");`